# How to collect same object in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to collect the same object in a compose function but only the first emit works. I know that only SharedFlows can emit the same object, but is there a way to collect in a similar way as collectAsState?

my object looks like

```
sealed class SomeUiState {
    object Loading : SomeUiState()
    data class Content(
        val friends: List<FriendModel>,
    ) : SomeUiState()

    object Error : SomeUiState()
}
```

I am re-emitting the Content class but with update friends values. I tried to override the hashCode() and equals() but had no success. The variable that emits is a SharedFlow, and i can see that it is emitting successfully by just collecting in the compose function but this doesnt allow me to use the data easily

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you emit a new value. Because it should work when emitting a new instance of data class of Content with a new list since equals and hashcode checks params in primary constructor

Comment: thanks for you comment, it lead me to the correct direction since now i was more confident that it should work. so im not fully sure how i can fix this, but i found the issue. my list has a data class, and im updating one field in that class (isUserOnline). i overrode the equals and hash of that data class and forced recomp, it is working that way. although, even adding new entries to that list wouldnt recomp, so im still confused, but if overridding is working i think i might just do that

Comment: You can check updated answer. Instead of `collectAsState` you can use `MutableState` with `neverEqualPolicy` which will trigger recomposition no matter which data you set. Default one is `structuralEqualityPolicy` which checks equals and hashCode methods of data class

Answer (score 1):

In this sample i'm able to collect with either collectAsState or setting value of MutableState in ViewModel. Passing a Content with new list should trigger recomposition.

But due to your data if you can't trigger recomposition you can change policy of `MutableState` from `structuralEqualityPolicy` to `neverEqualPolicy` trigger recomposition no matter which value of MutableState you set or `referentialEqualityPolicy` to trigger when new instance of data class is set. Default one checks equals and hashCode to trigger recomposition.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val uiStateMutableSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<SomeUiState>()
    var uiState by mutableStateOf<SomeUiState>(
        SomeUiState.Content(listOf()),
        policy = neverEqualPolicy()
    )

    init {
        uiStateMutableSharedFlow.onEach {
            uiState = it
        }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    fun emitValue() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            uiStateMutableSharedFlow.emit(
                SomeUiState.Content(
                    List(
                        size = Random.nextInt(1, 10)
                    ) {
                        FriendModel(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }

}

sealed class SomeUiState {
    object Loading : SomeUiState()
    data class Content(
        val friends: List<FriendModel>,
    ) : SomeUiState()

    object Error : SomeUiState()
}

data class FriendModel(val name: String)


@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    val viewModel = MyViewModel()
    SomeComposable(viewModel)
}

@Composable
private fun SomeComposable(viewModel: MyViewModel) {

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.emitValue()
            }
        ) {
            Text("Emit Value")
        }

         val uiState = viewModel.uiState


        if (uiState is SomeUiState.Content) {
            LazyColumn {
                items(
                    (uiState as SomeUiState.Content).friends
                ) { friendModel ->
                    Text(friendModel.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an acceptable solution too. but it would break my pattern.